# Phonetic reconstruction of "Haremhab"

Tags: phonology, cuneiform, egyptian

This is a follow-up question to [Hippopotamus - Egyptian ḫꜣb - a phonosemantic calque?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19294/hippopotamus-egyptian-%e1%b8%ab%ea%9c%a3b-a-phonosemantic-calque).

In a lecture by Jacobus van Dijk the pronounciation of the Egyptian *Haremhab* is clarified to be something different, perhaps *harmaha(?)* (0:14'42)<sup>1</sup> or *Arma'a*<sup>2</sup>.

Now I am worried what if anything this implies for *ḫꜣb* "hippo", and anyway, how do they rive at that reconstruction; via cuneiform if I understand correctly?

By the way, I am aware that *h* is not *ḫ*, but I haven't foundany examples of the latter.

---

1: The Charles K. Wilkinson Lecture Series: Rulers in Time of Transition. The MET. 2012 [[yt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eOYzyo0ATA&t=882)]

2: Wikipedia (de), Daḫamunzu-Affäre § Die Gleichsetzung von hethitisch Arma'a mit Haremhab [[de.WP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da%E1%B8%ABamunzu-Aff%C3%A4re#Die_Gleichsetzung_von_hethitisch_Arma%27a_mit_Haremhab)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Egyptian hieroglyphs, in general, only record consonants, not vowels. The hieroglyphic name of the pharaoh Horemheb records the consonants *ħr-m-ħb* with no indication of the vowels to be used.

This, of course, makes it very difficult to talk about these words in Egyptology classes or lectures. So a convention has arisen to add vowels to these words, **solely for the purpose of making them easier to talk about**: the consonants *j* and *y* are treated as `/i/`, *w* is treated as `/u/`, *ꜣ* and *ꜥ* are treated as `/a/`, and then `/ɛ/` (or sometimes `/o/`) is inserted as needed to make the word pronounceable. This is how we get from *ħr-m-ħb* to "Horemheb".

But this has nothing to do with the vowels the Egyptians actually used when pronouncing these words. By looking at transcriptions in cuneiform, which *does* indicate vowels, we can get a sense of the original pronunciation; it seems Horemheb's name was pronounced something like `/ħar'ma:.ħab/`.